# Confusion about the visibility and arbitration relations in a formal framework for distributed consistency models

Tags: pl.programming-languages, dc.distributed-comp, concurrency, formal-methods, consistency-models

In the POPL'14 paper "[Replicated Data Types: Specification, Verification, Optimality](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2535838.2535848)" and the book "[Principles of Eventual Consistency](https://www.nowpublishers.com/article/Details/PGL-011)", the authors propose a formal framework for specifying distributed consistency models via the $vis$ (visibility) and $ar$ (arbitration) relations.

> **Visibility** is an acyclic relation over operations. If an operation $a$ is visible to $b$, it means that the effect of $a$ is visible to the client performing $b$. $...$ We call two updates *concurrent* if they cannot see each other, *i.e.,* are not ordered by visibility.
>
> **Arbitration** is used to indicate how the system resolves *update conflicts*, *i.e.* how it handles concurrent updates that do not commute. It is a total order on operations. If an operation $a$ is arbitrated before $b$, it means that the system considers the operation $a$ to happen earlier than operation $b$.

A history $H$ (consisting of operations) satisfies a consistency guarantee $\mathcal{P}$ if it can be extended (by adding visibility and arbitration) to an abstract execution that satisfies them. One of the basic consistency guarantees is the *return value consistency*, which says that, in the context of read/write registers, each read should read from the last write visible ($vis$) to it according to the ordering specified by $ar$.

---

Given the background above, let us consider a simple consistency guarantee called *read my writes*:

> [*Read my writes*](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2013/12/169945-replicated-data-consistency-explained-through-baseball/fulltext) is a property that also applies to a sequence of operations performed by a single client. It guarantees the effects of all writes that were performed by the client are visible to the client's subsequent reads. If a client writes a new value for a data object and then reads this object, the read will return the value that was ***last written*** (emphasis added) by the client (or some other value that was later written by a different client).

The book above defines it as
$$\text{RMW} \triangleq (so \subseteq vis)$$ where $so$ denotes the "same session relation".

The CSUR'16 survey "Consistency in Non-Transactional Distributed Storage Systems" defines it as
$$\text{RMW} \triangleq \forall a \in H\vert_{wr}, \forall b \in H\vert_{rd}: a \to^{so} b \implies a \to^{vis} b \triangleq so\vert_{wr \to rd} \subseteq vis$$
where $wr$ and $rd$ denote the set of write operations and read operations, respectively.

However, I think these two definitions too weak to ensure the reads read from the *last* write, because they have specified only the visibility relation but not the arbitration relation. Without the arbitration order between the previous writes, a read may read from a stale write. Therefore, I think the definition for RMW should contain $so|_{wr} \subseteq ar$.

---

My questions are:

1. Are the two definitions for RMW correct? If not, what should it be?
2. More generally, what is the relationship between visibility and arbitration? Is it always required that $vis \subseteq ar$? If not, what are the consistency models that do not need $vis \subseteq ar$?

---

**Related Post:** [Confusion about a formal definition of PRAM consistency](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/41413/12739)